# Phonegap + Jquery Header / Footer disappear after Reloading the page

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

developing App on Android with Phonegap + Jquerymobile

1. i have a submit Form ..
2. after Submitting i have to reload the app in order to inject the new Offer added into the its category page.
3. when Ad-btn clicked and checking with the server through $.post .. success function --> reloading the page --> location.reload(true); ..going to the main page of the App .. the Header / Footer disappears ..
4. the Whole App in One html file with many data-role=pages...
5. even i tried to empty the div of its page-role before loading the whole app .. didn't work

Answer (score 0):

navigator.app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", {wait:2000, loadingDialog:"Wait,Loading App", loadUrlTimeoutValue: 60000});

this line fixed the issue .. thanks to

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1887779/darin-kolev